# Add swift UI support to the framework that target's IOS 10,

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-frameworks

I wrote framework on Swift UI, then Client told me that lower IOS was required to be supported on framework.

I rewrite framework on UIKit/UIViewController, And now I want to add swift UI application support in the framework.
While I was working on lib from my Swift UI application, target of the application was IOS 13, and framework's targets were IOS 10, I added swift UI support with `if #available(iOS 13.0, *)` checks. it worked perfectly from the project that targets IOS 13.

But when I opened the framework project to export it, It is telling me that code which is under the `if #available(iOS 13.0, *)` can't be complied. It does not know what is `UIHostingCOntroller, View, Binding` and any swift UI functions.

What to do? How to add Swift UI support to the framework that also should work on lower than IOS 13?

Comment: Even if you have deployment target iOS 10 you have to build your project with most recent SDK version to be capable to compline new features and link to new frameworks.

Comment: So what's the solution? When I set Target to 13.0 it builds nicely but then it will not be available lower IOS versions.

Answer (score -2):

Go to your project settings and change the target its simple

[do as follows you can change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTRrM.jpg)

Comment: click on this link there i a image to how to do